# Through error if multiple textboxes empty validation

Tags: javascript, html

I am using the following code to restrict the textbox to enter only number but when i am trying to validate textbox should not be empty its not working

```
    function AllowNumbersOnly(input, kbEvent) {       
            var keyCode, keyChar;
            keyCode = kbEvent.keyCode;
            if (window.event)
                keyCode = kbEvent.keyCode; 
            else
                keyCode = kbEvent.which;              
            if (keyCode == null) return true;            
            keyChar = String.fromCharCode(keyCode);
            var charSet = "0123456789";           
            if (charSet.indexOf(keyChar) != -1) return true;           
            if (keyCode == null || keyCode == 0 || keyCode == 8 || keyCode == 9 || keyCode == 13 || keyCode == 27) return true;
            return false;
            if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(txtTextBox.Text))
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Enter Value Please.", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Warning);           
            }
            else
            {
                alert("Fill the fields")
            }
        }
   </SCRIPT>
```

My HTML code is

```
    <form name="requirement" method="post" id="requirement" action="" enctype="multipart/form-data" class="niceform">
<input id="b_size1" name="b_size1" onkeypress="return AllowNumbersOnly(this,event)" type="text"  size="4" />
    <input id="b_size2" name="b_size2" onkeypress="return AllowNumbersOnly(this,event)" type="text"  size="4" />
    <input id="b_size3" name="b_size3" onkeypress="return AllowNumbersOnly(this,event)" type="text"  size="4" />
    <input id="b_size4" name="b_size4" onkeypress="return AllowNumbersOnly(this,event)" type="text"  size="4" /> 
    <input id="b_size5" name="b_size5" onkeypress="return AllowNumbersOnly(this,event)" type="text"  size="4" />
    <input id="b_sizeL" name="b_sizeL" onkeypress="return AllowNumbersOnly(this,event)" type="text"  size="4" />
    <input id="b_size6" name="b_size6" onkeypress="return AllowNumbersOnly(this,event)" type="text"  size="4" />
    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-green" value="Submit">
```

Please guide me what solution for this?

Comment: Why is there an unconditional `return false;` in your code?

Answer (score 0):

Your code doesn't reach the part where you check if it's empty. You allways exit your function with the `return false;` above it.

Comment: sorry.. i have to return it at the end but NULL condition is not working

Comment: that's not javascript, it's a c# function. You can just do: if (txtTextBox.Text)

Comment: thanks for suggestions.. i have changed this one but its not working